# Timestamps of start and end of month

Tags: php

How can one get the timestamps of the first and last minutes of any month using PHP?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use [`mktime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
$first_minute = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), 1);
$last_minute = mktime(23, 59, 59, date("n"), date("t"));
```

That is for the current month. If you want to have it for any month, you have change the month and day parameter accordingly.

If you want to generate it for every month, you can just loop:

```
$times  = array();
for($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
    $first_minute = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1);
    $last_minute = mktime(23, 59, 59, $month, date('t', $first_minute));
    $times[$month] = array($first_minute, $last_minute);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/hKst65Dx)

Comment: I believe in line "$last_minute = mktime(23, 59, 0, $month, date('t', $first_minute));" you need to replace "$first_minute" with "$month", because you want to know the number of days in this very month.

Comment: @PascalKlein it is correct with $first_minute because function date expects the timestamp as a second argument, not the month number.

Comment: @Pascal: What luka said... see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php... `$first_minute` might be a confusing variable name in this case, it really is a timestamp of the first minute of the month and `date('t', $first_minute)` extracts the number of days of the month in the timestamp.

Comment: For this interested in the "start and end of month" timestamps who would like to include those last 59 seconds, change `$last_minute` to `$last_minute = mktime(23, 59, 59, date("n"), date("t"));`

Comment: This is very nice.  date("t") is the key here.

Answer (score 16):

With PHP 5.3, you can do

```
$oFirst = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$oLast  = new DateTime('last day of this month');
$oLast->setTime(23, 59, 59);
```

In PHP 5.2

**Note**: *as [AllThecode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371699/allthecode) pointed out in the comments below, this next example **only** works if you do the `$oFirst` portion first.  If you add `+1 month` to `new DateTime` the result will jump an extra month ahead on the last day of the month (as of php 5.5.9).*

```
$oToday = new DateTime();
$iTime  = mktime(0, 0, 0, $oToday->format('m'), 1, $oToday->format('Y'));
$oFirst = new DateTime(date('r', $iTime));

$oLast  = clone $oFirst;
$oLast->modify('+1 month');
$oLast->modify('-1 day');
$oLast->setTime(23, 59, 59);
```

Comment: WARNING! I almost got burned by this. -1 month on the 31st of a month will give the 1st of the same month, NOT the previous month!

Comment: @AllTheCode, is "-1 month" a typo in your code or comment?  it's "+1 month" in the 5.2 example above.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use the original example. The same issue is for +1 month too. If today is the 31st of October (which it is) and you add one month, you will get December 1st, not November 30th.

Comment: Interesting. What version is that with?  5.2.x?  I just tried with 5.5.9 (which is what I'm running locally and on my servers) and it works correctly (returned 10-1 and 10-31)

Comment: I'm also on 5.5. Do this: `$d = new DateTime(); $d->modify('+1 month');`. The new $d value will show you the wrong value.

Comment: @AllTheCode I first tried it with `$oFirst` (as shown above) and it worked.  I thought maybe it was a timezone thing or something, but then did it exactly as you posted adding `+1 month` to `new DateTime` and I got November 30th.  Weird - and good catch.  Thanks for walking through this with me.

Comment: No problem. And btw this is not new to 5.5, it's always been like this. Oct 31st - 1 month = Oct 1st. Oct 31st + 1 month = Dec 1st.

Answer (score 4):

Use [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) for generating timestamps from hour/month/day/... values and [cal_days_in_month](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) to get the number of days in a month:

```
$month = 1; $year = 2011;
$firstMinute = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
$lastMinute = mktime(23, 59, 0, $month, $days, $year);
```

Comment: Thanks, but better to use $lastMinute = mktime(23, 59, 59, $month, $days, $year);

Comment: @Kir well, that would be the last second, but you're right - Updated it.

Answer (score 4):

I think better then

```
$first_minute = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), 1);
$last_minute = mktime(23, 59, 0, date("n"), date("t"));
```

is:

```
$first_minute = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), 1);
$last_minute = mktime(23, 59, 0, date("n") + 1, 0);
```

Comment: Its better because the date("t") is extra process that is not needed if you use a day of 0 with month + 1. [one less call to date()]

Answer (score 2):

This requires PHP > 5.2 and need adjustement for the "minutes" part

```
$year = ...;  // this is your year
$month = ...; // this is your month
$month = ($month < 10 ? '0' . $month : $month);
$start = new DateTime($year . '-' . $month . '-01 00:00:00');
$end = $start->modify('+1 month -1 day -1 minute'); //perhaps this need 3 "->modify"
echo $start->format('U');
echo $end->format('U');
```

(not tested)

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');//Current time
$date->modify("-1 month");//get last month
$startDate = $date->format('Y-m-01');
$endDate = $date->format('Y-m-t');
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Way do like this..

$first_day = date('m-01-Y h:i:s',strtotime("-1 months"));

$last_day  = date('m-t-Y h:i:s',strtotime("-1 months"));

Comment: This answer seems to provide the first and last day of the previous month, while the question wants to know the first and last minute of these days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of last month'));
 echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of last month'));
```