# How to find the start and end date of a previous month in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timestamps of start and end of month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702696/timestamps-of-start-and-end-of-month)

I want to find the Start and end Date of the previous month in php (ie) i want to find the last month start and end date of the current month

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+date+month

Answer (score 49):

I guess this would do

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of last month'));

echo "<br/>";

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of last month'));
```

Comment: Seems a joke but it really works! MAGIC!

Answer (score 6):

```
echo date('m-01',strtotime('last month')) . '<br/>';
echo date('m-t',strtotime('last month')) . '<br/>';
```

Comment: Nice answer, you can get current month start and end day too: `$fromDate = date('Y-m-01',strtotime('this month'));
  $toDate = date('Y-m-t',strtotime('this month'));`