# How to determine start (date) of previous month in a time loop?

Tags: php

The php code below describes a simulated time loop in which some actions must take place.

How to determine -for this time loop- the start date (sql format) of the previous month? (If it would have been reel time (no simulation) I noticed a solution ([How to find the start and end date of a previous month in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535379/how-to-find-the-start-and-end-date-of-a-previous-month-in-php)) )

```
$maxdays = 366;
$startthismonth_sql;
for($daynumber=0;$daynumber<$maxdays;$daynumber++){

  $currentdayval = "+".(string)($daynumber-$maxdays)." days";
  $date_sql = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($currentdayval)); //current date

  if($daynr != 1){
    $startthismonth_sql = date("Y-m-01",strtotime($currentdayval));
  }

  //$startpreviousmonth_sql = ??? //format yyyy-mm-dd

  //do some simulation stuff

}//for($daynumber=0;$daynumber<$maxdays;$daynumber++)
```

Comment: i don't understand. start date of which ever month is always 1. you mean the day like Monday, Tuesday, etc?

Comment: I need the complete date in yyyy-01-mm format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite easy:

```
$reference = strtotime('+70 days'); // this is what your simulation uses
$ts = strtotime('first day of last month', $reference);
echo date('Y-m-d', $ts);
```

The above code would show the first day of the month preceding the month 70 days from today in the specified format.

Comment: +1 Didn't know you could use those nice English phrases in `strtotime`!

Comment: @MichaelButler: It's not exactly a single recognized phrase, rather a combination of some [supported relative formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Comment: @Jon: thnx. However, when I just tested you code , at the first iteration when $date_sql = '2013-01-28', the date resulted by your code = '2013-10-01'.

Comment: Just to clarify (as I dont understand the number 70 in your code), I need the $startoflastmonth value in each iteration; e.g., $startoflastmonth changes in every iteration

Comment: @user2543182: Substitute `$currentdayval` from your code where I have `'+70 days'`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the start of THIS month is correctly `strtotime($currentdayval)`, the start of the previous month is:

`strtotime('-1 month', strtotime($currentdayval))`

That gives you the timestamp. All we're doing is subtracting 1 month from a given timestamp.

Comment: thnx for your suggestion. However, after testing your code it seems the code returns the date of a month ago, not of the start of previous month...

Comment: I said "assuming the start of THIS month is strtotime($currentdayval)" so I had a precondition. This should work: `strtotime($startthismonth_sql)` in your snippet above

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout mktime()

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

You can give `date("n") - 1` as month value to this function. It will even allow a negative month here and calculate the appropriate month from year before itself.