# Get start & end timestamp for month from Month and Year

Tags: php

I have following data:

```
Array
(
    [month] => 07
    [year] => 2014
)
```

I want start & end timestamp of july 2014 using above array.

Comment: mktime() http://php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php should be your friend. If you need the end timestamp of a given month (to check if a given timestamp is in that month), it might be easier get the timestamp of the first of next month and check if a given timestamp is smaller.

Comment: See this [link - timestamps-of-start-and-end-of-month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702696/timestamps-of-start-and-end-of-month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used functions: 
http://php.net//manual/ru/function.cal-days-in-month.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php

```
<?php
    $array = array('Month' => 07, 'Year' => 2014);

    $daysCount = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $array['Month'], $array['Year']); //obtain month days count

    $firstDay = mktime(0, 0, 0, $array['Month'], 1, $array['Year']); //obtain timestamp of specified month first day
    $lastDay = mktime(0, 0, 0, $array['Month'], $daysCount, $array['Year']); //obtain timestamp of specified month last day

    echo 'First: '.$firstDay.' Last: '.$lastDay;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$start_month_str = $array['year'] . '-' . $array['month'] . '-1 midnight';
$end_month_str = $start_month_str . ' + 1 month - 1 minute';

$start_month_stamp = strtotime($start_month_str);
$end_month_stamp = strtotime($end_month_str);
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/97mH1wx8)

---

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php